# check an array of string value with array of object in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have array of strings like this

```
let fromHour = ['2.5','3','3.5']
let toHour = ['2.5','3','3.5']
```

I have an array of object saved in mongoDB

```
timeRange = [
              {
                from:'2.5',
                to:'3'
              },
              {
                from:'3',
                to:'3.5'
               }

           ]
```

I want to check if any of my array of string value exist in that object value

I have tried this but it give me this error ( Unrecognized expression '$match' )

```
checkAppoint = await Appointment.aggregate([
                {
                  $project: {
                    date: myScheduleFinal[k].date,
                    status: { $in: ['pending', 'on-going'] },
                    timeRange: {
                      '$match': {
                        'from': { $in: fromHolder },
                        'to': { $in: toHolder },
                      },
                    },
                  },
                },
              ]);
```

also I have tried this solution and it work for me but it take to much time so I am trying this with aggregate

```
 checkAppoint = await Appointment.findOne({
                date: myScheduleFinal[k].date,
                status: { $in: ['pending', 'on-going'] },
                timeRange:{$elemMatch:{
                  from:{$in:fromHolder},
                  to:{$in:toHolder}
                }}
              });
```

So anyone have a solution for that

Answer (score 2):

Just try `$elemMatch` and `$in` operators,

- using `find()` method

```
checkAppoint = await Appointment.find({
  timeRange: {
    $elemMatch: {
      from: { $in: fromHour },
      to: { $in: toHour }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cZ_dHyQedxq)

---

- using `aggregate()` method

```
checkAppoint = await Appointment.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      timeRange: {
        $elemMatch: {
          from: { $in: fromHour },
          to: { $in: toHour }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/REwY23HfMrI)

Comment: It work but it still take to much time do you have another solution to do that with high speed

Comment: it may take time because it is iterating match with array element to array element, try giving compound multikey index on from and to field, like this `db.collectionName.createIndex( { "timeRange.from": 1, "timeRange.to": 1 } )` more information see [index-multikey](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#index-arrays-with-embedded-documents)

Comment: I have found a way around that ,I am now getting all my appointment in a specific day all at once and then do this elemMatch check after that ,This give me a high speed than keep requesting to database to check because fromHour and toHoure value will change in my for loop more than one time @turivishal

Comment: okay great i am glad you have resolved, you can post your solution as answer, if you think it is helpful then this answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found a way around to solve this problem and I will share the solution I used

First I want to minimize my request to mongodb so I am now making just one request that bring all the appointment with the required date
and I want to make it this way because my fromHour and toHour array will change many time through single request

helperArray => contains all the day I want to check it's range

```
let checkAppoint = await Appointment.find({
      date: { $in: helperArray },
      status: { $in: ['pending', 'on-going'] },
    });
```

now inside my for loop I will go through that data

```
  checkAppoint.filter((singleAppoint) => {
    if (singleAppoint._doc.date === myScheduleFinal[k].date) {
      singleAppoint._doc.timeRange.map((singleTime) => {
          if (fromHolder.includes(singleTime.from)) {
            busy = true;
        }
      });
    }
  });
```